# Quickbook PHP API - Http Response Body are null or Empty

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I need customer list from Quickbooks Account. Quickbooks API call is as below

```
$dataService = DataService::Configure(array(
            'auth_mode' => 'oauth1',
            'consumerKey' => '',
            'consumerSecret' => '',
            'accessTokenKey' => '',
            'accessTokenSecret' => '',
            'QBORealmID' => '',
            'baseUrl' => 'https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/'
        ));

$dataService->setLogLocation("./logs/");
$dataService->Query("SELECT * FROM Customer");
```

It gives error as below.

> Fatal error: Uncaught QuickBooksOnline\API\Exception\SdkException:
>   [0]: Http Status Code:[0] Http Response Body are null or Empty. thrown
>   in
>   Core/HttpClients/IntuitResponse.php
>   on line 26

Please suggest me that what I have done wrong?

Comment: Are you trying from the local machine? try checking network status. HTTP 0 throws when there is no connection to DNS.

Comment: No, I am trying this on the live site.

Comment: Write a simple PHP curl script to check whether you can access the following url quickbooks.api.intuit.com, It seems your server cannot connect to that URL.

Comment: Thanks @Thamaraiselvam, the curl_exec function was disabled. After enable, it is working!

Comment: Glad to know you found it. Happy coding !